# Регулярное выражение четных чисел

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Нужно написать регулярное выражение, которое будет соответствовать любому (положительному или отрицательному) четному числу, например, -4, 1000, -20и т. д.
У меня не получается

```
(?<![-\d])(?<!\d[.,])\d*\[24680](?![.,]?\d)
```

---

```
(?<![-\d])(?<!\d[.,])\d*\[24680](?![.,]?\d)
```

не работает

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Зачем вы откатываете изменения? Я вам всё отформатировал. Правда, регулярка была явно не от этого вопроса, слишком переусложнённая.

Comment: не знаю, что ищет ваша регулярка, но точно не четные целые числа. зачем там поиск точки и запятой? Искать нужно: 0 или 1 минус в начале (можно еще добавить 0 или 1 плюс ), потом последовательность из любого количества цифр, заканчивающуюся на [02468]

Comment: Вы вообще подумайте - что вы ищете регуляркой? Прям по пунктам распишите. А потом уже сама регулярка. Сначала понимание - что ищем то?

Comment: @Эникейщик Ещё что первый символ не ноль, если он единственный, надо как-то обыграть )  Но это уже детали.

Comment: `^-?(?:[1-9][0-9]*[02468]|[2468])$` - что бы не захватывать 0 или число не начиналось с 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы написать регулярное выражение, которое будет соответствовать любому четному числу включая отрицательные, можно использовать следующее выражение:

```
^-?\d*[02468]$
```

Это выражение состоит из нескольких частей:

- ^ - начало строки
- -? - необязательный символ минуса
- \d* - любое количество цифр
- [02468] - одна из цифр 0, 2, 4, 6, 8
- $ - конец строки

Таким образом, выражение будет соответствовать любому числу, начинающемуся с необязательного символа минуса, за которым следует любое количество цифр, заканчивающихся четной цифрой.